# MySQL Search Delimited, Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following database structure:

```
id | name         | size
-------------------------
1  | Men's Jacket | S,M,L
2  | Men's Jacket | M,L
3  | Men's Jacket | S
```

I want to get a result with `size` **M** only.

I know how to do it, using PHP's `explode()` & `foreach()`, but it takes too much memory for 10k+ products.

Comment: then fix your DB structure and normalize it, rendering the problem moot.

Comment: size table: prod_id, size. 1|S, 1|M, 1|L, 2|M etc

Answer (score -1):

**To get results of only M:** (ex 'M')

Update your sql to use a where clause of `where size = "M"`

**To get results that include M:** (ex 'M', 'S,M', 'S,M,L', 'M,L')

Update your sql to use a where clause of `where size like "%M%"`

Answer (score -1):

I've just learned about the MySQL's `find_in_set()` function:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE find_in_set('M', size)<>0
```